# ASP.NET MVC 3 MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am currently developing a site using ASP.NET MVC 3, I am using Nhibernate. I created a custom MembershipProvider as described below.

My question is time to record the user authentication in a session in ValidateUser method and retrieves it in GetUser.

From what I noticed you can not use Session in the ValidateUser, but it is not correct to use Cache, since the storage is not per user session.

How do I do?

```
class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        var membershipUser = MyMembershipUser)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(username);

        // Is not possible
        // var membershipUser = (MyMembershipUser) HttpContext.Current.Session[username];

        return membershipUser;
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var usuario = UsuarioRepository.GetUsuarioAuthentication(username, password);

        if (usuario != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(username, new MyMembershipUser(usuario.Id, usuario.Email), null,
                                          Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, FormsAuthentication.Timeout,
                                          CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

            // Is not possible 
            // HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(username, new MyMembershipUser(usuario.Id, usuario.Email));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Don't add it in the ValidateUser method.  If ValidateUser returns true, add it at that time in the web app.

Comment: But in the GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline) method I need to return a MembershipUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Session is not involved at all when you use ASP.NET Membership with Forms Authentication.

Once the user has successfully authenticated, simply call

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()
```

and an authenication cookie is automatically created for you. Don't call this in ValidateUser(), but rather from the client code that calls ValidateUser().

The authentication cookie is completely independent of the session cookie.

Refer [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) on MSDN for more info.

If you want to cache your authenticated user's user details, again this should be done in the client code that calls Membership.ValidateUser(), not in the membership provider itself. **The membership provider GetUser() and ValidateUser() should do as their names suggest, and not have any other side effects.**

Comment: Actually, I am using a custom Membership, that is why call GetUser

Comment: @Michel The same pattern applies no matter what Membership Provider you choose to use. You call Membership.Validate(), then if successful, call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie().

Comment: Yes. Saille is right. Session has no place in a Custom Membership Provider. After you create your Custom Membership Provider, you can store some of that information in Session if you really desire.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. For instance, during my authentication process, a successful authentication will return some information that I want to store in the session. But since the session hasn't been created yet (until I return from the the method), the Session is null. Is there a way to initialize the session from the ValidateUser method??

Comment: Consider using ASP.NET Profile instead of Session as the interface to user-specific info.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to get the user from the session.  GetUser is for retrieving the user from the database - returning a populated MembershipUser object.

Comment: By chance is there another way? In a request for this method is called two times or more.

Comment: Is it called two times or more within the same process? If so, then you need to re-write that code. If it is called two times or more within your application, then that is fine. That is why you have abstracted Membership into a class, because you are using it in multiple places.

Comment: If you just need the user name, User.Identity.Name does the trick.  If you need all of the properties on the MembershipUser object, you can cache the object - use the username as the cachekey.  I can only make suggestions as I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation for those two methods should just query your database and return a `MembershipUser` or validate the username password - don't worry about `HttpContext`.

I don't know the specifics of your `UsuarioRepository` implementation so I've just made some methods up, but you should code your provider roughly like this:

```
class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        var usuario = UsuarioRepository.GetUserByUserName(username);
        return new MyMembershipUser(usuario.Id, usuario.Email);
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return UsuarioRepository.ValidateUser(username, password);              
    }
}
```

The `UsuarioRepository.GetUserByUserName(username)` method would just return the user with the given username, while `UsuarioRepository.ValidateUser(username, password)` should return true if the password is correct for the given username.  The repository would deal with getting a Session, and doing the query.

Then, to improve the performance of your provider, you can use some of the built in caching abilities of NHibernate to make sure it caches the results of these queries by modifying your `UsuarioRepository` methods to use caching.  Then the multiple calls to these methods won't have a performance hit.

Comment: Stank, that's is perfect, but my GetUser method is called 4 times sometimes in a single request, is it normal?

Comment: No, that is not normal.  Are you calling it anywhere explicitly?  What do the `membership` and `authentication` sections in your `web.config` look like?

Comment: that looks OK.  So the action you have for `~/Login` should take the user to the login screen, and the POST from that screen should validate the user using your membership provider, and if the user is authenticated it should call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie)` which should then set a cookie which confirms that the user is authorised.

Answer (score 1):

Are you concerned with finding storing information about the user?

With MVC you can always call

```
        User.Identity.Name
```

This will provide you with the current username of the User.

As @Saille mentioned above, you need to only concern yourself about the basics of Creating a `MembershipUser` and validating a `MembershipUser` when creating your own Custom Membership Provider.

After you have done the basics and created your provider, you can then store the information into `Session` when the successfully user logs in.